# Checking Image (NSImage) Resolutions Leaks Memory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, nsimage

I have a function that returns the resolutions of images (NSImage).  The application allows the user to select a folder, and it will list the resolutions of each file in it with an NSMutableArray-backed list (NSTableView).

```
- (NSSize)getImageResolutions:(NSString *)path {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] init];
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
    CGImageSourceRef source = NULL;
    if (url) {
        source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url,NULL);
        if (source) {
            NSDictionary *props = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
            NSString *width = [props objectForKey:@"DPIWidth"];
            NSString *height = [props objectForKey:@"DPIHeight"];
            NSSize size;
            if ([width floatValue] > 0 && [height floatValue] > 0) {
                size = NSMakeSize([width floatValue],[height floatValue]);
                return size;
            }
            else {
                NSImage *img0 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
                NSArray *imageReps = [[NSArray alloc] init];
                imageReps = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepsWithContentsOfFile:path];
                NSInteger width = 0;
                NSInteger height = 0;
                for (NSImageRep *imageRep in imageReps) {
                    if ([imageRep pixelsWide] > width) width = [imageRep pixelsWide];
                    if ([imageRep pixelsHigh] > height) height = [imageRep pixelsHigh];
                }
                NSImage *imageNSImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize((CGFloat)width,(CGFloat)height)];
                [imageNSImage addRepresentations:imageReps];
                NSImage *img1 = imageNSImage;
                return NSMakeSize(img1.size.width/img0.size.width*72.0f,img1.size.height/img0.size.height*72.0f);
            }
        } else {
            return NSMakeSize(0,0);
        }
    } else {
        return NSMakeSize(0,0);
    }

    CFRelease(source);
}
```

If I select a folder containing some 200 images, the memory usage will rise by about 100 MB.  There's a definitely a leak.  And I've traced the source to the function above.  I'm 100% certain that's the source because if I don't use the function above the app memory will rise by no more than 10 MB with a folder of more than 200 images.  I have made some adjustments like adding CFRelease(source).  But there's no change.  How can I stop the leak?

Muchos thankos.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `CFRelease(source);` will never be executed.

```
NSDictionary *props = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
NSString *width = [props objectForKey:@"DPIWidth"];
NSString *height = [props objectForKey:@"DPIHeight"];
CFRelease(source);
```

should stop your memory leaking.

Comment: That's a solution for stopping my memory leak?

Comment: Yeah, using `CFRelease(source);` properly after calling `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL` may stop memory leaking.

Comment: @ElTomato - They have a point here.  Your `CFRelease(source)` is unreachable.

Comment: How would I improve it, then?